# Reload currently loaded UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm a novice iOS developer developing a quiz app that has a countdown timer of 30 secs. In the middle of the timer execution the user can press a Refresh button. When the user presses the button, I would like to invalidate the timer (reset the timer back to 30 sec countdown), do the view controller animation and reload the same view controller. I tried many things and the only thing that works fine is do this on the Refresh button click:

```
 CurrenlyLoadedUIViewController1 *currentlyLoadeduiViewController = 
 [[CurrenlyLoadedUIViewController1 alloc] init];
 [currentlyLoadeduiViewController 
 setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
 [self currentlyLoadeduiViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I don't know whether this will induce a memory leak as I'm thinking I'm not releasing the currently loaded one.

Please help.

Comment: There is no need to reload the view controller. Just re-initialize all the related iVars that you may have initilized in viewDidLoad: . You will need to invalidate the timer as you say. You can do all that in the IBAction method that you connect to the reload-button. What do you mean by "do the view controller animation"?

Comment: thanks for the comment. if you see the above code, I would like to do everything as I would when the user starts from scratch. I was referring to the UIViewController setModalTransitionStyle that I had shown above. In other words, when refresh button is clicked, I would like to do the same exact thing as above (as if the user starts the quiz for the first time) by reloading the UIView controller completely without inducing any memory leaks.

Comment: That is the code where you instanciate and display the view controller for the first time. If you insist of doing exactly the same then you need to react to the reload action by making the presenting view controller dismiss the view controller, create a new one, load it and display it the usual way. But that is not what I would do. I would just set all related values to its original value, discard and re-fire the timer and problably add some proper animation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ARC, you don't need to worry about releasing the existing view controller; the compiler will do it for you. If you aren't using ARC, but you are using synthesized properties, then the compiler will still handle the memory management for you. If you write your own accessor methods and are not using ARC, just ensure that the your accessor methods obey the memory management rules of accessor methods. If you aren't using your accessor methods, then release the old ivar before overwriting it with the new value.

Edited:
As far as replacing a view controller, you need to carefully distinguish between the view controller and its view.

The view controller doesn't need to be reloaded, although that's fine. But the same object which originally loaded it should also be the object that reloads it. Always think in terms of objects, responsibility, and relationships (object ownership).

Usually you do something like this:

```
- (void)resetCurrentViewController {
    UIViewController *old = self.currentViewController;
    UIView *oldView = old.view
    UIView *superview = [oldView superview];
    UIViewController *new = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    UIView *newView = new.view;
    [UIView transitionWithView:superview
       duration:0.2
       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
       animations:^{ [oldView removeFromSuperview]; [containerView addSubview:newView]; }
       completion:^{ self.currentViewController = new; }];
}
```

This is written in the edit box, not from real code, using stand-in variable names. The basics is that "self" (whatever that is) "owns" the "currentViewController", and replaces the current copy with a new copy, while at the same time swapping the old view for the new one, which one assumes will have the new values.

But as another commenter said, this seems like overkill. You could alternately reset all the values in the view controller (implement a -reset method in the view controller to do that) and the view (including any text fields or other controls), wrapping the view updates in an animation so you get a nice fade. But there are lots of different ways to do it.

Comment: Thats reassuring and I'm using ARC with iOS6 but I'm not using storyboards. Btw, I would like to reconfirm this. I'm showing a viewController and in the middle of the quiz, the user can change his mind and start all over. At this point, I would like to animate the controller (setModalTransitionStyle), invalidate the timer and load the controller as if the user is doing it for the first time. I was reading in here where some people were saying it is bad to add code from the currently viewed controller to reload it.

Comment: How you reload a view controller depends on how that controller was added in the first place. If you're in a navigation controller, you will probably have to pop it and push a replacement. An instance method of an object will continue to run even if that instance is freed in the middle of the method, so you absolutely cannot access ivars, but otherwise it's not seriously bad. It might be confusing to code maintainers. Better to move the logic into a parent view controller or the app delegate.

Comment: I'm not using navigation controllers at all. just plain view controllers. Btw, in the code above inside the Refresh button, if I add dismiss code to dismiss the current view controller and have the remaining code (as above) run, I get BAD_ACCESS error. If I comment out the dismiss code, all is fine. Since you mentioned that using ARC, the runtime will take care of releasing the loaded uiview controller, I think the code is good.

Comment: The last line of code in the snippet in your question appears garbled.

Comment: This is the line of code: [self currentlyLoadeduiViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: I guess there's a dot missing (or some braces), since that line of code as written would not compile. Should be: `[[self currentlyLoadeduiViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UIView do these jobs.